# AngularJS calculating totals for several same objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a front end which has a table of orders. Each order may be delivered, not delivered or partially delivered. I need to calculate totals based on which option is selected (so total is filtered also), and I did come to a solution, but I know I am overcomplicating things, I am not really an AngularJS dev.

```
function calculateTotals(){

    vm.sales.total_amount = {'_': 0, '_not': 0, '_part': 0, '_done': 0, 'n-p': 0};
    vm.sales.total_price = {'_': 0, '_not': 0, '_part': 0, '_done': 0, 'n-p': 0};
    vm.sales.order_total_price = {'_': 0, '_not': 0, '_part': 0, '_done': 0, 'n-p': 0};
    vm.sales.order_total_amount = {'_': 0, '_not': 0, '_part': 0, '_done': 0, 'n-p': 0};

    angular.forEach(vm.sales, function (sale) {
        angular.forEach(vm.sales.total_amount, function(value, key){
            vm.sales.total_amount[key] += (sale.status == key) ? sale.total_amount * 1 : 0;
            vm.sales.total_price[key] += (sale.status == key) ? sale.total_price * 1 : 0;
            vm.sales.order_total_amount[key] += (sale.status == key) ? sale.order_total_amount * 1 : 0;
            vm.sales.order_total_price[key] += (sale.status == key) ? sale.order_total_price * 1 : 0;
        });
        vm.sales.total_amount['_'] += sale.total_amount * 1;
        vm.sales.total_price['_'] += sale.total_price * 1;
        vm.sales.order_total_amount['_'] += sale.order_total_amount * 1;
        vm.sales.order_total_price['_'] += sale.order_total_price * 1;
    });

    vm.sales.total_amount['_'] = vm.sales.total_amount['_'] - vm.sales.total_amount['n-p'];
    vm.sales.total_price['_'] = vm.sales.total_price['_'] - vm.sales.total_price['n-p'];
    vm.sales.order_total_amount['_'] = vm.sales.order_total_amount['_'] - vm.sales.order_total_amount['n-p'];
    vm.sales.order_total_price['_'] = vm.sales.order_total_price['_'] - vm.sales.order_total_price['n-p'];
}
```

There are 4 variables I need in front, total amount and total price (sum of many deliveries, coming summed up from the Laravel back end), order total price and order total amount (fetching from Laravel back end).

How can I simplify this?

**EDIT** thanks to [stej4n](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7557538/stej4n) I've came up to this...though I still feel it can go simpler

```
function calculateTotals() {

    var properties = ['total_amount', 'total_price', 'order_total_amount', 'order_total_price'];
    var keys = ['_', '_not', '_part', '_done', 'n-p'];

    angular.forEach(properties, function (prop) {
        vm.sales[prop] = {'_': 0, '_not': 0, '_part': 0, '_done': 0, 'n-p': 0};
    });

    angular.forEach(vm.sales, function (sale) {
        angular.forEach(properties, function (prop) {
            vm.sales[prop]['_'] += sale[prop] * 1;
            angular.forEach(keys, function (key) {
                vm.sales[prop][key] += (sale.status == key) ? sale[prop] * 1 : 0;
            });
        });
    });

    angular.forEach(properties, function (prop) {
        vm.sales[prop]['_'] -= vm.sales[prop]['n-p'];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4 last lines can already be simplified this way :

```
angular.forEach(['total_amount', 'total_price', 'order_total_amount'], function(prop) {
   vm.sales[prop] -= vm.sales[prop]['n-p'];
});
```

Where does `(sale.status == key)` come from ? `status` property does not exists in any object of vm.sales ?

Additional optimization: remove every `* 1`, it shouldn't change anything ^^

Comment: vm.sales is a collection fetched from back-end. Each sale has a status

Comment: I think you can safely remove every `* 1`